# Problem with sending an email via php script?

Tags: php, webforms, contact-form

I've had something strange happen lately with php script I use to send emails from an online contact form and just wondered if any one could shed a little light on the issue.

I've had a php script which I use on multiple websites and it has always worked fine, but for some strange reason, I tried using in on one site and it just wasn't working.

I tried fiddleing with it and eventually realised that it was something to do with the following section of code:

this is the original section of code that usually works fine, but wasn't working for some reason:

```
$to = 'My Name <info@mydomain.com>';
```

I then removed the name bit, so that the code looked like this:

```
$to = 'info@mydomain.com';
```

and now it sends the email through ok.

As I say, the top code usually works fine, so any ideas why this time I had to alter the code to get it to work?

Any possible explanations would be great :o)

Here's the full code:

```
<?php

require("is_email.php"); // email validation function

//Retrieve form data.   
//GET - user submitted data using AJAX  
//POST - in case user does not support javascript, we'll use POST instead  
$name = ($_GET['name']) ?$_GET['name'] : $_POST['name'];  
$email = ($_GET['email']) ?$_GET['email'] : $_POST['email'];  
$telephone = ($_GET['telephone']) ?$_GET['telephone'] : $_POST['telephone'];
$address = ($_GET['address']) ?$_GET['address'] : $_POST['address'];
$enquiry = ($_GET['enquiry']) ?$_GET['enquiry'] : $_POST['enquiry'];
$calculation = ($_GET['calculation']) ?$_GET['calculation'] : $_POST['calculation']; 

//flag to indicate which method it uses. If POST set it to 1  
if ($_POST) $post=1;

//Server side validation for POST data
if (!$name) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and enter your name.';  
if (!$email) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and enter your email.'; 
else if (!is_email($email)) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back as you may have entered an invalid email address.';
if (!$telephone) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and enter your telephone number.';
if (!$address) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and enter your address.';
if (!$enquiry) $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and enter your enquiry.';
if ($calculation != '14') $errors[count($errors)] = 'Please click back and check you have correctly answered the simple calculation (in number format).';

//if the errors array is empty, send the mail  
if (!$errors) {

    //recipient - change this to your name and email  
    $to = 'info@mydomain.com';     
    //sender  
    $from = $name . ' <' . $email . '>';

    //subject and the html message  
    $subject = 'Website Enquiry: ' . $name;   
    $email_body = '  
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
    <head></head>  
    <body>  
    <table cellpadding="5" style="color:#757575;">  
        <tr><td style="color:#3b5998;">Name: </td><td>' . $name . '</td></tr>  
        <tr><td style="color:#3b5998;">Email: </td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>  
        <tr><td style="color:#3b5998;">Telephone: </td><td>' . $telephone . '</td></tr>
        <tr valign="top"><td style="color:#3b5998;">Address: </td><td>' . nl2br($address) . '</td></tr>
        <tr valign="top"><td style="color:#3b5998;">Enquiry: </td><td>' . nl2br($enquiry) . '</td></tr>  
    </table>  
    </body>  
    </html>';

    //send the mail  
    $result = sendmail($to, $subject, $email_body, $from);

    //if POST was used, display the message straight away  
    if ($_POST) {  
        if ($result) echo 'Thank you! We have received your message.<br /><br /><a href="../enquiry_form.html">OK</a>';  
        else echo 'Sorry, unexpected error. Please try again later';

        //else if GET was used, return the boolean value so that   
        //ajax script can react accordingly  
        //1 means success, 0 means failed  
        } else {  
            echo $result;     
        }

//if the errors array has values  
} else {

    //display the errors message  
    for ($i=0; $i<count($errors); $i++) echo $errors[$i] . '<br />';    
    exit;  
}

//Simple mail function with HTML header  
function sendmail($to, $subject, $email_body, $from) {  
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";  
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";  

    $result = mail($to,$subject,$email_body,$headers);  

    if ($result) return 1;  
    else return 0;  
}  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my initial question to explain how I overcame the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hosts can vary on their requirements for `sendmail` and depending on what `sendmail` software they are using. You may take this up with your hosting company and see if there are any caveats to making it work or if they know a better format.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there an advantage in having the name and the email address following the $to = ? it's just I can't think just now why it is an advantage. Thanks again for any input :o)

Comment: The only reason I can think of is just display preferences when the client opens an email. It would show from `My Name` with the top line, with the bottom it would show from the `info@domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$mailFrom = '"My Name" <info@mydomain.com>';
```

the FROM label is double quoted and a space and `<email>`

Comment: How are you mailing ? using the mail() function OR opening a SMTP connection via script ?

Comment: Hi Stewie, I've added the full code under my original post. I'm not that well up on php really.